# Quick way to turn of the network connectivity for debug purposes?

Tags: iphone, networking, dropbox

Is there a straight forward way to "brut force" the network connection (cellular and WIFI) off  and back on on an iphone?   I'm working on an application that syncs through dropbox and would like to test & debug my error recovery code from lost connections.

UPDATE: I should have been a bit more specific, I want to turn this off in sw. For example after launching a request to dropbox, I want to simulate a failed download by turning off the network.

Comment: You will probably not be able to manipulate the iPhones connectivity just from your application. I'm definitely no expert on iPhone programming, but Have you thought about using timers or interrupting the function that downloads the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Settings, and turn Airplane Mode **on** to disable all network connections; **off** to re-enable.

**EDIT**: To enable Airplane Mode using iOS SDK (2.x and maybe 3.x), try [Erica Sadun's code](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/bring-airplane-mode-control-ba.html):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIApplication.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Framework Paths
#define SBSERVPATH  "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices"
#define UIKITPATH "/System/Library/Framework/UIKit.framework/UIKit"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   //
   // For testing try issuing the following: 
   //         ap y; sleep 5; ./ap n
   //

   if (argc < 2)
   {
      printf("Usage: %s (y | n)\n", argv[0]);
      exit(-1);
   }

   // Argument used to switch airplane mode off or on
   BOOL yorn = [[[NSString stringWithCString:argv[1]] 
                    uppercaseString] hasPrefix:@"Y"];

   // Fetch the SpringBoard server port
   mach_port_t *p;
   void *uikit = dlopen(UIKITPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
   int (*SBSSpringBoardServerPort)() = 
         dlsym(uikit, "SBSSpringBoardServerPort");
   p = SBSSpringBoardServerPort(); 
   dlclose(uikit);

   // Link to SBSetAirplaneModeEnabled
   void *sbserv = dlopen(SBSERVPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
   int (*setAPMode)(mach_port_t* port, BOOL yorn) = 
         dlsym(sbserv, "SBSetAirplaneModeEnabled");
   setAPMode(p, yorn);
   dlclose(sbserv);

   [pool release];
}
```

Comment: How to do that thing in ios 6.0 and later

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a failed download in software, just close the connection prematurely in software when some debug flag is set.

I prefer pulling the cable from wifi access point.

ADDED:

If your wifi access point has a locally accessible admin web page, and you are an admin, you might be able to figure out the HTTP(S) sequences to access the access points WAN configuration page and disable/re-enable the WAN.  You could do all this in software.

Answer (score 0):

### On the simulator

Download and install [Network Link Conditioner](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools) from Apple. It is a part of “Additional Tools” package. Open the DMG, navigate to the “Hardware” directory, and double-click “Network Link Condition.prefPane”.
Network Link Conditioner is going to appear as a preference pane at the bottom of System Preferences.
You can choose from one of the following presets, or create your own for particular requirements:

- 100% Loss
- 3G
- DSL
- EDGE
- High Latency DNS
- LTE
- Very Bad Network
- WiFi
- WiFi 802.11ac

Enabling/disabling preset is just one click away.

### On the device

You can enable and configure the Network Link Conditioner on your iOS device under Settings > Developer > Networking. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/update-developer-options) if Developer section doesn't show.